# How to reduce Orchard Deployment Solution?

Tags: orchardcms

I am successfully exclude all db and log files from the Orchard Solution project.

however, the deployment package is still almost **20 Mb.**

Is there other files that I may exclude from the Orchard Solution which can significantly

reduce the deployment size?

The current size is not very efficient for msdeploy ftp deployment.

Comment: this question may be better answered if asked on the orchard discussions page http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions

Answer (score 2):

20MB is pretty typical and really not a lot. There is not much you can remove unless you start slashing out modules.